# Android Linearlayout rotate?

Tags: android

I need to rotate the linearlayout with it's child view's. Now I am using android 2.2 but in Android 3.0 has a rotate option.If we set the rotation degree we can get the rotated view.

> setRotation(float rotation)

I need to rotate my view by using android 2.2. How to do this in android 2.2 .Can any one suggest me to do .... !!

Note: I need to rotate the view relevant to it's touch position

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create this drawable, say rotation.xml:

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

Now set this drawable in the `android:src` tag of your view.